# render template flask data not displaying

Tags: python, sqlite, templates, flask

I have such functions

```
def main():
    ''' Demonstrate UDF '''
    with sqlite3.connect("User.db") as conn:
        conn.row_factory = dict_factory
        conn.create_function("date_parse", 1, date_parse)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        rows  =  cur.execute("SELECT Status,date_parse(DateEntered) as 'DateEntered', EnteredBy, DateModified, AccountName,SalesRepName FROM data WHERE Status!=''and EnteredBy!=''  order by DateEntered asc ").fetchall()

def date_parse(s):
    ''' Converts a string to a date '''
    try:
        t = parser.parse(s, parser.parserinfo(dayfirst=True))
        return t.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
    except:
        return None

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    ''' Helper for dict row results '''
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d
```

When i use

```
for row in rows:
    print (row)
```

i get all data i need, ordered in a proper way,buy when i want to display it on my web app , i get exception

```
@app.route('/Accont/')

def SetUp():
    # ...code 
    return render_template('navbar.html',rows = rows)
```

i tried to render template without request, directly from jinga2 , but that does not help me. Anybody can help me to display that data in proper order on my web app?

Navbar.html

```
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>DateEntered</th>
        <th>EnteredBy</th>
        <th>DateModified</th>
        <th>AccountName</th>
        <th>SalesRepName</th>




              </thead>
              <tbody>


                {% for row in rows %}
```

```
                <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[5]}}</td>
```

```
          {%endfor%}
```

got this error : sqlite3.OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception

Comment: What exception? Show the full traceback here. Also show your template.

Comment: If you change `d` as follows `d = OrderedDict()` in `dict_factory` function It will keep insert order. Dont forget to import `from collections import OrderedDict`

Comment: thanks for answer,but that does not helped me

Comment: Also post the full code for the setup function.

Comment: same as in main function